# When running 'npm run build' it won't create a build directory

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, npm-build

I am a bit new using React still. I am trying to make my git repo visible to GitHub-pages.

When running the `npm run build` , it successfully complies but it won't create a build folder.

In result, when I try to run `npm run deploy` it complies until I receive this error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/alejandro/Documents/FSMX/FSMX/build'`

here is my `package.json` code

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "FSM X Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
```

Here is my `index.html` code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./src/images/test.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="FSMX Experience"
    />
    <title>FSMX Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create the "build" folder on /Users/alejandro/Documents/FSMX/FSMX and try again

Comment: When I created the build folder it didnt want to run... since it didn't have anything inside.

Comment: When I created a "build" folder, I got this error: The pattern in the "src" property didn't match any files.